# Resource Not Found Error: When Reading CSV from Azure Blob using Pandas with its SAS URL

Tags: python, pandas, azure, azure-devops, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to perform Dataset versioning where I read a CSV file into a pandas DataFrame and then create a new version of an Azure ML Dataset. I am running the below code in an Azure CLI job within Azure DevOps.

```
df = pd.read_csv(blob_sas_url)
```

At this line, I get a 404 Error.
Error Message:

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: The specified resource does not exist
```

I tried to do this locally, I was able to read the csv file into Dataframe.
The SAS URL and token are not expired too.

How to solve this issue?

Edit - Code

```
def __init__(self, args):
    self.args = args
    self.run = Run.get_context()
    self.workspace = self.run.experiment.workspace

def get_Dataframe(self):

    print(self.args.blob_sas_url)
    df = pd.read_csv(self.args.blob_sas_url)

    return df


def create_pipeline(self):
    print("Creating Pipeline")
    print(self.args.blob_sas_url)

    dataframe = self.dataset_to_update()
    # Rest of Code

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Azure ML Dataset Versioning pipeline')

    parser.add_argument('--blob_sas_url', type=str, help='SAS URL to the Data File in Blob Storage')
    
    args = parser.parse_args()
    ds_versioner = Pipeline(args)
    ds_versioner.create_pipeline()
```

In both the instances where I print the SAS URL within the script `print(self.args.blob_sas_url)`, the URL is shortened. I was able to see this in the std_log.txt file.

Comment: what are the network rules of your storage account?

Comment: @Fnaxiom it is enabled for all networks

Comment: hmm, maybe you can print out the `blob_sas_url` in your cli job to see what's actually being parsed?

Comment: how is `blob_sas_url` injected into your code? (btw, you might want to trim out your comment because that is sensitive info)

Comment: @Fnaxiom Thank you for heads up regarding the comment. I pass it as an argument to the python script

Comment: can you edit your question and show the code that gets the sas token and pass it to the line that has python script? we should know where that information gets trimmed.

Comment: when you run your script like `python yourscript.py --blob_sas_url $VARIABLE`, how does the `$VARIABLE` come in?

Comment: I use Azure Variable Groups to get the variable. 
So it goes as --blob_sas_url $(azml.sasURL)

Comment: what happens when you try this ` --blob_sas_url "$(azml.sasURL)"`?

Comment: good then. I will add it as an answer for future reference.

Comment: Sure @Fnaxiom that will be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of shortening or technically trimming your input argument is that the bash variable is split at the `&` level. so all the rest of your sas url goes as "commands" or other "arguments". Apparently that is how azure parses it.

eg:

```
python3 test_input.py --blob_sas_url "somepath/to/storage/account/file.txt?sv=2022-01-01&sr=b&sig=SOmethingwd21dd1"
>>> output:  somepath/to/storage/account/file.txt?sv=2022-01-01&sr=b&sig=SOmethingwd21dd1

python3 test_input.py --blob_sas_url somepath/to/storage/account/file.txt?sv=2022-01-01&sr=b&sig=SOmethingwd21dd1
>>> output:  
[1] 1961
[2] 1962
[2]+  Done                    sr=b
```

so you just need to quote your Azure variable in your step command like follows:

`python3 your_python_script.py --blob_sas_url "$(azml.sasURL)"`